# Get all permutations of string array without duplicates for any element

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, permutation

I have a textbox on a sheet to get its value to be used as the criteria of AutoFilter.
The value of textbox is numbers and the multiplication factor is asterisk "`*`".
There is no issue if the value is only one string e.g "`2`" or "`5`".
But, there are cases that the string will be like "`1*2`" or "`10*12*14`"
The problem is order of the multiplied numbers differs from someone input to another one,
Meaning: "`1*2`" can be inputted as "`2*1` by another one"
and "`10*12*14`"  can be inputted as "`12*10*14`" or "`14*12*10`" and so on.
**So,** if the value of textbox contains multiplied numbers, then:
I need to get all possible permutations of string array without duplicates on any element (as stated earlier).
the expected result will be used as the **criteria of AutoFilter.**
I tried the below code and it dose not work as I need, as it produce a lot of duplicates of array elements.

```
Sub Main()
    
    Dim size As Long, c As Variant, n As Long, arr
    Dim tbx4 As String, factors() As String
    
    tbx4 = "10*12*14"  'ActiveSheet.TextBox4.value
        
    factors = Split(tbx4, "*")
    
    size = UBound(factors) + 1
    c = factors
    
    n = UBound(c) + 1:   ReDim arr(size - 1)
    
    EmbeddedLoops 0, size, c, n, arr
    
End Sub
 
Function EmbeddedLoops(index, k, c, n, arr)
  Dim i As Variant
    If index >= k Then
        PrintArrayOnSingleLine arr
    Else
        For Each i In c
            arr(index) = i
            EmbeddedLoops index + 1, k, c, n, arr
        Next i
    End If
End Function
 
Sub PrintArrayOnSingleLine(myArray As Variant)
  Dim counter As Integer, textArray As String
    For counter = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        textArray = textArray & myArray(counter)
    Next counter
    Debug.Print textArray
End Sub
```

Comment: Read up on the ArrayList object.  SOunds like your issue might be helped by the ArrayList Sort method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Main()
    
    Dim n As Long, i As Long, k As Long, ptr As Long, possibles As Long, arr() As String
    Dim tbx4 As String, factors() As String

    tbx4 = "10*12*14*16*18"  'ActiveSheet.TextBox4.value
        
    factors = Split(tbx4, "*")
    
    n = UBound(factors)
    
    k = n
    possibles = n + 1
    
    Do While k > 1
        possibles = possibles * k
        k = k - 1
    Loop
    
    ReDim arr(possibles - 1)
    ptr = 0
    
    For i = 0 To n
        Call FillArray(arr, factors, ptr)
    Next
    
    Dim tmp As String
    For k = 0 To possibles - 1
        arr(k) = Right(arr(k), Len(arr(k)) - 1)
        Debug.Print arr(k)
    Next
    
    
End Sub
 
Sub FillArray(arr() As String, elements() As String, ByRef ptr As Long)

    Dim i As Integer, k As Integer, l As Integer, element As String, possibles As Integer, m As Integer
    Dim subelements() As String, subptr As Long
    Dim subarr() As String
    
    ptr = 0
    For i = 0 To UBound(elements)
        element = elements(i)
        If UBound(elements) > 0 Then
            ReDim subelements(UBound(elements) - 1)
            l = 0
            For k = 0 To UBound(elements)
                If k <> i Then
                    subelements(l) = elements(k)
                    l = l + 1
                End If
            Next
            possibles = UBound(subelements) + 1
            m = possibles - 1
            Do While m > 1
                possibles = possibles * m
                m = m - 1
            Loop
            ReDim subarr(possibles - 1)
            subptr = 0
            Call FillArray(subarr, subelements, subptr)
            If UBound(subelements) = 0 Then
                arr(ptr) = "*" + element + "*" + subelements(0)
                ptr = ptr + 1
            Else
                For m = 0 To UBound(subarr)
                    arr(ptr) = "*" + element + subarr(m)
                    ptr = ptr + 1
                Next
            End If
        End If
    Next
    

End Sub
```

By way of explanation.  Firstly I calculate the number of possible permutations.  For any number of factors n, the number of permutations is given by n * n - 1 * n - 2 ... until n - x is 1.  Effectively we only need to go down to * 2, since * 1 yields the same answer.  I then dimension the answer array accordingly.

We then need an iterative function to fill this array with the possible values.  Note that I am passing a pointer by reference into this function.  This is because I am filling the answers by a fixed pattern, to ensure completeness.  Take a,b,c,d as examples.  There are 24 possible combinations: these I generate effectively in batches of six, starting with each of the given letters, so the first six in the answer begin with a and the last 6 with d. But my outer loop in this case would only run four times, hence the requirement for a pointer that gets advanced within the iterative function.  Obviously your case is easier with only three factors, but I have written my answer to be extensible.

Comment: It just needs a small a adaption, each element of the result array should contains the multiplication factor asterisk "`*`" e.g for simplicity  if  `tbx4 = "10*12"` then expected result array will be (`10*12 , 12*10`)

Comment: Now it works perfectly as it should. Please, I know `Call` is obsolete , But when I tried to remove it I got syntax error.

Comment: If you want to remove `Call`, then you need to remove the parentheses around the parameters.  E.g. just `FillArray subarr, subelements, subptr`

Comment: I found a new problem due to using asterisks on the code itself , e.g  if `tbx4="4*1"` and then used the final array `arr` as **criteria of AutoFilter**, then some incorrect values are added to the result , like `24*10 , 10*24 , 4*10` , Please how to fix this issue?

Comment: Please ask a new question, if necessary referencing this question.